# Excel Function to SUMIF using another workbook as a reference with individual tabs of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 workbooks. Workbook Alpha and Workbook Beta. Workbook Alpha is pulling data from Workbook Beta. Workbook Beta has 100s of tabs each labeled as a day "1-1-24" and contains data that Workbook Alpha needs. Workbook Alpha then Index matches off of each tab per column.

Is there a way to be able to drag this formula across on Workbook Alpha without having to type the date in the formula of CTRL + H each time to change the formula the date is referencing?

Example below of Workbook Alpha:

Column A

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[New Data Daily Sales Data Pack V2.xlsx]1-17-24 GA'!$N$2:$N$20,
   MATCH($C8,'[New Data Daily Sales Data Pack V2.xlsx]1-17-24 GA'!$S$2:$S$20,0)),0)
```

Column B

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[New Data Daily Sales Data Pack V2.xlsx]1-18-24 GA'!$N$2:$N$20,
   MATCH($C8,'[New Data Daily Sales Data Pack V2.xlsx]1-18-24 GA'!$S$2:$S$20,0)),0)
```

As you can see the tab/date is the only thing changing and I don't want to control + H each time I drag the formula to change the date/tab reference. I can also reference the date in Workbook Alpha in case that helps.

I feel like the problem can be solved with INDIRECT? I also have the ability to reference the date in Workbook Alpha to help find which tab I need in Workbook Beta I just don't know how to get to the solution.

Comment: Try putting in row 1 the different dates and then use indirect to build the reference. I would suggest just testing indirect across a few sheets before you go across workbooks, especially if you share workbooks with others as the path can become an issue. Note there are some good examples of the use of indirect already on here.